# Deploying a site from VSS

Tags: asp.net, visual-sourcesafe

In answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102833/how-do-i-use-aspnet-with-visual-studio-2008) Joel Coehoorn said

> Finally, only after the site's gone through a suitable QA process, the production server is updated from source control, not from within visual studio.

Does VSS Explorer have tools for deploying sites (via FTP, I would assume)? I noticed for the first time a Web/Deploy menu option, but it's grayed out. How does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Managing Web Content Using MS Visual SourceSafe](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/archive/itsolutions/intranet/plan/webvss.mspx)

yes you can deploy via ftp or network share using the "web deploy" feature in the VSS explorer.

Answer (score 2):

VSS has a pretty comprehensive set of command line arguments.  The best way I know is to write a batch file to:

1 - Get Latest to the local system (presumably a clean build machine)

2 - Push the newly-updated local files to your FTP site.

Answer (score 0):

We use Nant for our project. Nant is a dot net port of ant for java. It has tasks to checkout from VSS, compile and deploy.

- [Nant](http://nant.sf.net)
- [VSS checkout task](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/vsscheckout.html)
- [Codeproject Article on deployment with Nant](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/webappbuild_Nant.aspx)